# How not to allow the user to highlight the text present in a JTextArea? But can only I highlight the text?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I would like not to allow the user to highlight the text present in a text area, but that only I can modify the text present. I don't want the user to be able to copy and paste the text in the text area, but he must still be able to see the words highlighted inside. I've already tried this method: `textArea.setHighlighter(null);` but it doesn't work

```
    class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter 
{
    public MyHighlightPainter(Color color) { super(color); }
}
Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = new MyHighlightPainter(Color.yellow);

public void Highligh(JTextComponent textComp, String pattern) 
{
    try {
        Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
        Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
        String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()), 
               upperText = text.toUpperCase(), upperPattern = pattern.toUpperCase();
        for(int pos = 0; (pos = upperText.indexOf(upperPattern, pos))>=0; pos += pattern.length())
            hilite.addHighlight(pos, pos+pattern.length(), myHighlightPainter);
    } catch (Exception e) {} 
}

vocabolario.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                textArea.setText("");
                 String[] parziale = new String[6000];
                 try {
                        String p1 = "SELECT definizione FROM Cherubini WHERE definizione LIKE '%", p2 = "%';", px = vocabolario.getText(), query = p1+px+p2;
                        ResultSet rs =  Main.conn().createStatement().executeQuery(query);
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                             String[] dati =  { rs.getString("definizione") };
                             for(int i = 0; i < dati.length; i++) { 
                                 parziale[i] = dati[i]; 
                                 textArea.append(parziale[i]+"\n\n\n"); 
                             }
                        }
                        Highligh(textArea,vocabolario.getText()); 
                 }
                 catch(SQLException exc) {} 
            }

        });
```

Comment: You should be using the "Swing" tag is you want Swing developers to notice your question. This is the second time I added the tag.

Comment: In your last question you were asked to post an [mre] with every question. The code above is not an "MRE". We can't compile that code. We don't have access to your database. An "MRE" would be a JFrame with a JTextArea with some text and then you manually add a highlight.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works:

```
textArea.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"), "none");
```

Comment: This will prevent the copying of text, but it will not prevent the user from "selecting" text. This can be confusing since the user will still see the selection painted on the text.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like not to allow the user to highlight the text present in a text area

The user can't "highlight" text in the text area. That is functionality that is  controlled by your application code. Highlighted text can't be copied.

The user can "select" text in the text area. The user can select text using the mouse or keyboard. Selected text can be copied.

The default copy functionality only works on "selected" text. You can prevent the user selection of text by using a custom `Caret`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NoTextSelectionCaret extends DefaultCaret
{
    public NoTextSelectionCaret(JTextComponent textComponent)
    {
        setBlinkRate( textComponent.getCaret().getBlinkRate() );
        //textComponent.setHighlighter( null );
    }

    @Override
    public int getMark()
    {
        return getDot();
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        super.focusGained(e);
        setSelectionVisible(false);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("No Text Selection Allowed");
        textField1.setCaret( new NoTextSelectionCaret( textField1 ) );
//      textField1.setEditable(false);

        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Text Selection Allowed");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("No Text Selection Caret");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Comment: But this use the method  textArea.setHighlighter(null); that no works

Comment: @KrishnaPilato, I see what you mean. Made a change to prevent the selection from being painted without removing the highlighter

Comment: yes exactly! I'd like to do it. but your code doesn't works, what Have I to copy (methods)?

Comment: The static methods are just demo code to demonstrate how the the class works. You just need to use the class and reset the Caret on your text area.